# Sonarqube 4.5.4 : MySQL deadlock

Tags: mysql, sonarqube, deadlock, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

I am using sonarqube 4.5.4 with mysql database.

I got this exception when running analysis on my projects :

```
INFO  o.d.m.sonar.runner.RunSonarVisitor - ### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
2016-02-23 04:05:40.091Z  INFO  o.d.m.sonar.runner.RunSonarVisitor - ### The error may involve org.sonar.core.user.RoleMapper.insertGroupRole-Inline
2016-02-23 04:05:40.091Z  INFO  o.d.m.sonar.runner.RunSonarVisitor - ### The error occurred while setting parameters
2016-02-23 04:05:40.091Z  INFO  o.d.m.sonar.runner.RunSonarVisitor - ### SQL: INSERT INTO group_roles (group_id, resource_id, role)     VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Here is the output of  `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` :

```
=====================================
 2016-02-23 11:54:18 2b4ff4306700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
 =====================================
 Per second averages calculated from the last 12 seconds
 -----------------
 BACKGROUND THREAD
 -----------------
 srv_master_thread loops: 1238940 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 970355 srv_idle
 srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0
 ----------
 SEMAPHORES
 ----------
 OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 13330
 OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 13521
 Mutex spin waits 1600127, rounds 719929, OS waits 5121
 RW-shared spins 6726, rounds 123969, OS waits 2815
 RW-excl spins 37472, rounds 641436, OS waits 2190
 Spin rounds per wait: 0.45 mutex, 18.43 RW-shared, 17.12 RW-excl
 ------------------------
 LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
 ------------------------
 2016-02-23 05:33:42 2b5258087700
 *** (1) TRANSACTION:
 TRANSACTION 21846827, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
 mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
 LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
 MySQL thread id 48914, OS thread handle 0x2b4ff2fbf700, query id 74518517 10.166.12.78 root update
 INSERT INTO group_roles (group_id, resource_id, role)
     VALUES (1, 209803, 'admin')
 *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
 RECORD LOCKS space id 279 page no 410 n bits 1 index `group_roles_resource` of table `sonar`.`group_roles` trx id 21846827 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
 Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
  0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

 *** (2) TRANSACTION:
 TRANSACTION 21846828, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
 mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
 LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
 MySQL thread id 48921, OS thread handle 0x2b4ff4347700, query id 74518515 10.166.11.36 root update
 INSERT INTO group_roles (group_id, resource_id, role)
     VALUES (1, 209804, 'admin')
 *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
 RECORD LOCKS space id 279 page no 410 n bits 1 index `group_roles_resource` of table `sonar`.`group_roles` trx id 21846828 lock_mode X
 Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
  0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

 *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
 RECORD LOCKS space id 279 page no 410 n bits 1 index `group_roles_resource` of table `sonar`.`group_roles` trx id 21846828 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
 Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
  0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

 ------------
 TRANSACTIONS
 ------------
 Trx id counter 22243718
 Purge done for trx's n:o < 22161699 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
 History list length 771
 LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
 ---TRANSACTION 0, not started
 MySQL thread id 49478, OS thread handle 0x2b4ff4306700, query id 75735427 10.166.1.176 root init
 SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
 ---TRANSACTION 22243294, not started
 MySQL thread id 49477, OS thread handle 0x2b4ff2fbf700, query id 75735410 10.166.1.176 root cleaned up
 ---TRANSACTION 22242581, not started
 MySQL thread id 49474, OS thread handle 0x2b4ff4306700, query id 75735009 10.166.1.98 root delayed send ok done
 ---TRANSACTION 17172416, not started
 MySQL thread id 42774, OS thread handle 0x2b4ff2efc700, query id 60565077 10.166.1.98 root cleaned up
 ---TRANSACTION 22243715, not started
 MySQL thread id 10, OS thread handle 0x2b4fef6dd700, query id 75735423 localhost rdsadmin delayed send ok done
 --------
 FILE I/O
 --------
 I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
 I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
 I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
 I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
 I/O thread 4 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
 I/O thread 5 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
 I/O thread 6 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
 I/O thread 7 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
 I/O thread 8 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
 I/O thread 9 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
 Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
  ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
 Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
 2704 OS file reads, 2704 OS file writes, 0 OS fsyncs
 0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
 -------------------------------------
 INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
 -------------------------------------
 Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
 merged operations:
  insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
 discarded operations:
  insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
 Adaptive hash table 0: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 1: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 2: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 3: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 4: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 5: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 6: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 7: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 8: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 9: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 10: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 11: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 12: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 13: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 14: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 15: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 16: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 17: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 18: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 19: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 20: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 21: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 22: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 23: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 24: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 25: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 26: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 27: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 28: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 29: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 30: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 Adaptive hash table 31: Hash table size 495359, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
 0.00 hash searches/s, 44.91 non-hash searches/s
 ---
 LOG
 ---
 Log sequence number 8204
 Log flushed up to   8204
 Pages flushed up to 8204
 Last checkpoint at  8192
 0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
 0 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
 ----------------------
 BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
 ----------------------
 Total memory allocated 0; in additional pool allocated 0
 Dictionary memory allocated 1951054
 Buffer pool size   488518
 Free buffers       79640
 Database pages     408878
 Old database pages 150893
 Modified db pages  0
 Pending reads 0
 Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0 single page 0
 Pages made young 38024, not young 16
 0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
 Pages read 200, created 428488, written 0
 0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
 Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
 Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
 LRU len: 408878, unzip_LRU len: 0
 I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
 ----------------------
 INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
 ----------------------
 ---BUFFER POOL 0
 Buffer pool size   244259
 Free buffers       40396
 Database pages     203863
 Old database pages 75234
 Modified db pages  0
 Pending reads 0
 Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0 single page 0
 Pages made young 19914, not young 12
 0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
 Pages read 106, created 212739, written 0
 0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
 Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
 Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
 LRU len: 203863, unzip_LRU len: 0
 I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
 ---BUFFER POOL 1
 Buffer pool size   244259
 Free buffers       39244
 Database pages     205015
 Old database pages 75659
 Modified db pages  0
 Pending reads 0
 Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0 single page 0
 Pages made young 18110, not young 4
 0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
 Pages read 94, created 215749, written 0
 0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
 Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
 Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
 LRU len: 205015, unzip_LRU len: 0
 I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
 --------------
 ROW OPERATIONS
 --------------
 0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
 0 read views open inside InnoDB
 Main thread process no. 4380, id 47632657958656, state: sleeping
 Number of rows inserted 18537127, updated 1761791, deleted 1114846, read 1897702042
 0.00 inserts/s, 0.50 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 4.00 reads/s
 ----------------------------
 END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
 ============================
```

Could you help me please.

Comment: Already asked on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361413/sonarqube-5-2-mysqltransactionrollbackexception-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-g

Comment: yep but not the same case as I am not upgrading sonar-qube version and there was no answer for that question.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE group_roles` and explain where the `INSERT` comes from.

Comment: Reference in SonarQube's backlog : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6613

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog = 1` in your config?

Here is [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog): effectively that means `select for update` makes table lock. More information about [locks in innodb](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html).

Still there are some question marks here, but that is my first idea. If that is still a problem... let's start from that binlog settings.